# 'Category' object is not subscriptable Django

Tags: python, django, api, orm

I am learning Django. I wrote a simple model and some views method in Django rest framework so that I can modify some particular attributes when needed to all the records that need that. Here is the model:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, I created this view to modify the isActive session when I call it:

```
class CategoriesChangeActiveView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            categories = request.data.get('categories')
            for category in categories:
                category = Category.objects.get(id=category['id'])
                category.isActive = category['isActive']
                category.save()
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': 'Bad request'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response({'success': 'Active changed'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Even when the format of my request is correct ( I debugged each line ) when it comes to the line category.isActive = category['isActive']`it throws the error that`'Category' object is not subscriptable`. I don't know why or how to fix it.

I saw in the official documentation, on older StackOverflow questions that this is doable, but I don't understand why I can't.

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a simple mistake.

Simply change it as follows and it should be fixed:

```
categories = request.data.get('categories')
for category in categories:
    category_obj = Category.objects.get(id=category['id'])
    category_obj.isActive = category['isActive']
    category_obj.save()
```

What you're doing is changing what the variable `category` is. You for loop and the unpacked variable is `category`, but then you get the model object and set the variable as `category`

So initially, the `category` variable is in fact a dictionary object, but you change it to be a django model object instance.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the issue is here:

```
category = Category.objects.get(id=category['id'])
category.isActive = category['isActive']
```

You set `category` to be an instance of the Category model (which in this case corresponds to a db record, but that bit is a little irrelevant).

Accessing attributes on a class instance is not done by the square bracket notation, but rather dot notation.

So instead of `category['isActive']` use `category.isActive`

If category was a dictionary, eg.

```
category = {
    "name": "cat",
    "isActive": True,
}
```

Then you would use the square bracket notation as `category["isActive"]` to get that value.

As it is, it's not a dict, so python thinks you are trying to subscript  the instance somehow, which will not work.